# Why won't Monotype Corsiva display in browser?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

Why is the font-family not being applied?

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class='reelShelf'>
    <div class="reel creatures" id="horseReel">
    <div class="reelTitle">Avi &amp; Rosie</div>
    <img class="photo" src="photos/creatures/horse1.jpg" onclick="fullView('creatures/horse1')" />
    <img class="photo" src="photos/creatures/horse2.jpg" onclick="fullView('creatures/horse2')" />
    <img class="photo" src="photos/creatures/horse3.jpg" onclick="fullView('creatures/horse3')" />
    <img class="photo" src="photos/creatures/horse4.jpg" onclick="fullView('creatures/horse4')" />
    <img class="photo" src="photos/creatures/horse5.jpg" onclick="fullView('creatures/horse5')" />
    <img class="photo" src="photos/creatures/horse6.jpg" onclick="fullView('creatures/horse6')" />
    <img class="photo" src="photos/creatures/horse7.jpg" onclick="fullView('creatures/horse7')" />
    <img class="photo" src="photos/creatures/horse8.jpg" onclick="fullView('creatures/horse8')" />
    <img class="photo" src="photos/creatures/horse9.jpg" onclick="fullView('creatures/horse9')" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: Corsiva;
    src: url(fonts/MTCORSVA.TFF);
}
.reelTitle
{
   color: white;
   flex: 0 0 auto;
   width: 100%;
   font-family: Corsiva;
}
```

And finally, here is a photo for reference:
[image: view of web browser]

Comment: Might be a typo here?: "src: url(fonts/MTCORSVA.TFF);" (corsIva..)

Comment: Nope, triple checked all the spelling. Thanks tho!

Comment: Is the file extension correct? I have a `MTCORSVA.TTF` on my computer, but no `.TFF`.

Answer (score 0):

You missed single quotes around the font-family.

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'Corsiva';
    src: url(fonts/MTCORSVA.TFF);
}
.reelTitle
{
   color: white;
   flex: 0 0 auto;
   width: 100%;
   font-family: 'Corsiva';
}
```